# Difficulties in solving a system of differential equations with a matrix differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, matrix, warning-messages, stochastic-calculus

I'm trying to solve a system of differential equations that looks like this:

```
Q = 1;
z[t_] := Sqrt[1/3 (y[t]^2/2 + V[x[t]] + r[t])];
z0 := Sqrt[1/3 (y0^2/2 + x0^(2 n)/(2 n) + r0)];
k = 100*z0;

a[t_] := x[t]^2;
b[t_] := 4*r[t]*(k/g[t]) + y[t];
c[t_] := x[t] + y[t]*g[t];
d[t_] := 1 + 4*r[t];

A[t_] := {{a[t], b[t]},{c[t], d[t]}};
B[t_] := {{0}, {-Sqrt[x[t]^alpha]}};
J[t_] := {{j1[t], j2[t]}, {j3[t], j24[t]}};

sys = {x'[t] == y[t]/z[t],
   y'[t] == -3 (1 + Q) y[t] - x[t]/z[t],
   r'[t] == -4 r[t] + 3 Q*y[t]^2,
   g'[t] == g[t],
   J'[t] == -A[t].J[t] - J[t].Transpose[A[t]] + B[t].Transpose[B[t]]};

ICs = {x[0] == 15, y[0] == -0.8, r[0] == 0.005, g[0] == 1, 
   J[0] == {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}};

soln = NDSolve[{sys, ICs}, {x[t], y[t], r[t], J[t], g[t]}, {t, 0, 10},
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}]
```

The difference between this and my real code is that, `A` and `J` must be 4x4 matrices. I have no idea how to resolve this. Mathematica returns the error:

```
NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.
```

But I can't figure out how to write such a problem for 2x2 or 4x4 matrices.

*-------- Update ---------*

In small versions the suggestion worked great, however for my problem:

```
    ClearAll["Global`*"]
    Mp = 1; 
    gstar = 228.75; 
    Cr := gstar*(Pi^2/30); 
    lambda = 1; 
    V0 := 1; 
    n = 1; 
    c = 0.012;

   V[x_] := x^(2*n)/(2*n); 
   dV[x_] := D[V[x], x]; 
   ddV[x_] := D[dV[x], x]; 
   T[t_] := (r[t]/Cr)^(1/4); 
  
   Q = 1; 
   z[t_] := Sqrt[(1/3)*(y[t]^2/2 + V[x[t]] + r[t])]; 
   z0 := Sqrt[(1/3)*(y0^2/2 + x0^(2*n)/(2*n) + r0)]; 
   k = 100*z0; 
   beta = 1; 
   alpha = 0; 
   gamma[t_] := c*x[t]^alpha*T[t]^beta; 
   gammaT[t_] := c*x[t]^alpha*beta*T[t]^(beta - 1); 
   gammaPhi[t_] := c*alpha*x[t]^(alpha - 1)*T[t]^beta; 


   fpsi[t_] := 1 + k^2/(3*1^2*z[t]^2) - y[t]^2/6; 
   frho[t_] := 1/(6*z[t]^2); 
   fdphi[t_] := y[t]/6; 
   fphi[t_] := x[t]/(6*z[t]^2); 
   gpsi[t_] := (c*x[t]^alpha*T[t]^beta)*z[t]*y[t]^2 - 
  (k^2/(3*1^2))* ((2*k^2)/(a[t]^2*z[t]^2)) - y[t]^2; 

   grho[t_] := 4 - (((c*x[t]^alpha*beta*T[t]^(beta - 
   1))*z[t]*T[t])/(4*r[t]))*y[t]^2 - k^2/(3*1^2*z[t]^2); 

   gphi[t_] := (-(k^2/(3*a[t]^2*z[t]^2)))*(3*z[t]^2*y[t] + (dV[x] 
   /.{x -> x[t]})) - z[t]*(c*alpha*x[t]^(alpha - 
   1)*T[t]^beta)*y[t]^2;


   gdphi[t_] := (-(k^2/(3*1^2) + 2* 
  (c*x[t]^alpha*T[t]^beta)*z[t]))*y[t];

  hpsi[t_] := (2*x[t]^3)/z[t]^2 + 
  ((c*x[t]^alpha*T[t]^beta)/z[t])*y[t]; 

  hrho[t_] := ((T[t]*(c*x[t]^alpha*beta*T[t]^(beta - 
   1)))/(4*r[t]*z[t]))*y[t]; 

  hdphi[t_] := 3 + (c*x[t]^alpha*T[t]^beta)/z[t] + (1/z[t])*((1/2)* 
   (x[t]^2/2/x[t]^2)); 

   hphi[t_] := k^2/(z[t]^2*1^2) + (ddV[x] /. {x -> x[t]})/z[t]^2 + 
  ((c*alpha*x[t]^(alpha - 1)*T[t]^beta)/z[t])*y[t];
```

Matrices are formed with these components:

```
  A[t_] := {{fpsi[t], frho[t], fdphi[t], fphi[t]}, 
  {gpsi[t] + 4*r[t]*fpsi[t], grho[t] + 4*r[t]*frho[t],
   gdphi[t] + 4*r[t]*fdphi[t], gphi[t] + 4*r[t]*fphi[t]}, 
   {hpsi[t] + 4*y[t]*fpsi[t], hrho[t] + 4*y[t]*frho[t], hdphi[t] + 
    4*y[t]*fdphi[t], hphi[t] + 4*y[t]*fphi[t]}, {0, 0, -1, 0}}; 


  B[t_] := {{0}, {(-Sqrt[2*(c*x[t]^alpha*T[t]^beta)*z[t]* 
  (T[t]/1^3)])*y[t]}, {Sqrt[2*(c*x[t]^alpha*T[t]^beta)* 
  (T[t]/(a[t]*z[t])^3)]}, {0}}; 

   J[t_] := {{j11[t], j12[t], j13[t], j14[t]}, {j21[t], j22[t], 
   j23[t], j24[t]}, {j31[t], j32[t], j33[t], j34[t]}, {j41[t], 
   j42[t], j43[t], j44[t]}}; 

   sys = {x'[t] == y[t]/z[t],
    y'[t] == -3 (1 + Q) y[t] - x[t]/z[t],
    r'[t] == -4 r[t] + 3 Q*y[t]^2,
    a'[t] == a[t],
    J'[t] == -A[t].J[t] - J[t].Transpose[A[t]] + 
    B[t].Transpose[B[t]]};

    ICs = {x[0] == 15,
     y[0] == -0.8,
     r[0] == 0.005, 
     a[0] == 1, 
    j11[0] = 0, j12[0] = 0, j13[0] = 0, j14[0] = 0, j21[0] == 0, 
    j22[0] == 0, j23[0] == 0, j24[0] == 0, j31[0] == 0, 
    j32[0] == 0, j33[0] == 1 + I*100, j34[0] == -1 + I*100, 
    j41[0] == 0, j42[0] == 0, j43[0] == 1 + 100, j44[0] == 1}; 


     Block[{n, r0, x0, y0, alpha, beta}, {n, r0, x0, y0, alpha, 
     beta} = {1, 0.005, 15, -0.8, 0, 1}; 
     soln = NDSolve[{sys, ICs}, Flatten[{x[t], y[t], r[t], J[t], 
     a[t]}], 
     {t, 0, 10}, Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}]]
```

I received the error:

```
 Equation or list of equations expected instead of 0 in the first \
 argument.
```

And I don't know how to solve it. It must be something simple but I can't see it.

-------- UPDATE 2 ----------

The problem was the part where I wrote 'V[x[t]]', instead I directly write x[t]^2/2, and in the parts where dV[x] appears I write x[t] etc. ... Now it's settled. Thanks.

Comment: You seemed to have some misplaced backticks in your code, which I tried to fix. You might want to check my edit.. You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: The following checks your system and shows that some of the functions are parameters are undefined (at least in the posted code): `Solve[sys, D[Flatten@{x[t], y[t], r[t], J[t], g[t]}, t]] /. t -> 0 /. Solve[ICs, Flatten@{x[t], y[t], r[t], J[t], g[t]} /. t -> 0]`

Comment: Oh thanks, it was my first question, I'll look at this link, it will be very helpful thanks,

Comment: Yes it's true, when writing the example I forgot to add some things like n = 1;
z[t_] := Sqrt[1/3 (y[t]^2/2 + x[t] + r[t])];
x0 = 15;
y0 = -0.8;
r0 = 0.0005;z0 := Sqrt[1/3 (y0^2/2 + x0^(2 n)/(2 n) + r0)];

But, I believe that this type of system can be solved by writing: NDSolve[sys, D[Flatten@{x[t], y[t], r[t], J[t], g[t]}, t] ] /.
   t -> 0 /.
  Solve[ICs, Flatten@{x[t], y[t], r[t], J[t], g[t]} /. t -> 0]

Comment: If those particular value cause a problem for `NDSolve`, then you should edit the question to include them. Otherwise, I think my answer will show the correct approach.

Answer (score 4):

If I fill in arbitrarily chosen values for the missing parameters and functions, `NDSolve` computes a solution. Note the use of `Flatten`, which is not necessary for success, but it produces a more useful output. (Personally, I'd leave off the `[t]` and solve for `{x, y,...}`, but I like that form of solution better than the `x[t] ->...` form.)

```
Block[{n, r0, x0, y0, alpha, V},
 {n, r0, x0, y0, alpha, V} = {2, 1, 1, 1, 1, # &};
 soln = NDSolve[{sys, ICs}, 
   Flatten@{x[t], y[t], r[t], J[t], g[t]}, {t, 0, 10}, 
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching"}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh thank you very much, I believe this will help me a lot. I'll test it in my real code and any updates I'll comment here.